# 02 Mustang GT 4.6

Tags: ford, rough-idle, mustang

I was on my way to work and car started to run rough stumble and check engine light started to flash. Immediately turned around limped home about 3 miles. Changed plugs and swapped some old coils around. Still idles low and strong gas smell from exhaust. Any ideas need my car for work.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We need more information. Can you plug in a scan tool and see if there are any codes?

Comment: Also, after you get the codes, check the fuel pressure at the rail and tell us the reading.

Comment: No i dont have a scan tool or fuel pressure gauge.I know the car is running lean.strong gas smell out the pipes.im getting at a minute of air releasing after i shut it off.sounds like passenger side up near radiator.4th and 5th gear it will bog and cough.any help.appreciated.

Comment: Swapping coils and changing plugs will not make a quick fix. You need to plug in a scan tool and retrieve data. There are over 1000 reasons that check engine light can come on. Thats why diagnostics are important. If you take it to a parts store they will usually scan it for you.

Comment: I dont know its a good idea to drive it.when i tested it from plug change it bogged worse as i went.a couple blocks.any ideas at all.

Comment: If you smell "a strong gas smell out the pipes", you are running rich, not lean. If so, you may at this point have clogged the cat, which is causing the bog. At what RPM does it bog down? Does it do it even in neutral? Can you rev it much past 3000 rpm?

Comment: It will idle between 5 and 700.but but seems to misfire.popping and stuttering.so yes it idles in neutral.it will rev perfectly.but on the road at about 50 in 4th and 5th it will stumble.within a mile im losing power.even in lower gears.

Comment: @KevinHaight   Have you had any luck at resolving the issue?

Comment: I get the codes clear.a day later its running rough again and reading misfires.to top it off  i try to start it today turn the key nothing.turn it 4 or 5 times boom it starts.changed fuel filter yesterday running pretty good.after the change back to misfire codes.check engine light flashing.Dont know if the dead ignition is the switch or i heard it could be the alternator diode which will throw these codes.if its a bad relay for the ignition could that also throw these codes.running out of ideas and money..also i think i can hear air back toward the firewall but not sure.any suggestions

Comment: For us to help you, you need to pull the codes so that we can better guide you. Else this question is ripe for closure.

Comment: I get po300 po116 po304 po174 ive changed plugs coil packs egr mass air flow tps a new cat.people tell me crank position sensor.is that possibly it.checkrd for vacuum leaks also.

Comment: Have you identified where the leaking air sound is coming from?  This could be causing all your problems?

Comment: CHECK THE CODES AND POST EM... or close this junk. We can't reach through the Internet to troubleshoot any further. Any answers you'll receive are just best guesses.

Comment: @NickG - he did post the codes in the comments

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have a bad Engine Coolant Temperature Sensor (ECT in Ford nomenclature). The code P0116,the smell of gas, and the rough idle are all symptoms of a bad ECT. Its Ford's part number **F5AF-12A648-AA**. Get the OEM part. Its about $25. Be careful replacing it because your car has a plastic intake manifold that tends to break.

Comment: I also changed the ect sensor the crank sensor the cam sensor and the egr.now i get po116 and the po304.could a dirty cold air intake filter cause the misfire in #4 and the 116 code which is misfire detected in first 1000 reolutions after start up.

Comment: Is the car modified in any way?

Comment: No big mods cold air and exhaust

Answer (score 2):

Based on the codes, I'd say [*race fever*'s spot on](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/23666/675):

> <kbd>[**P0300**](http://www.obd-codes.com/p0300)</kbd> - *Random/Multiple Cylinder Misfire Detected*
>
> <kbd>[**P0116**](http://www.obd-codes.com/p0116)</kbd> - *Engine Coolant Temperature (ECT) Circuit Range/Performance Problem*
>
> <kbd>[**P0304**](http://www.obd-codes.com/p0304)</kbd> - *Cylinder #4 Misfire Detected*
>
> <kbd>[**P0174**](http://www.obd-codes.com/p0174)</kbd> - *System Too Lean (Bank 2)*

---

### Explanation

I believe what's happening is the coolant temperature sensor is giving no signal or a signal that's out of the normal range (P0116).

Under such circumstances, it wouldn't surprise me if the ECU assumes a default temperature which is an under-prediction when the temperature is warm (engine running rich, smell of fuel in the exhaust) and an over-prediction when the temperature is cold (resulting in the misfire codes).

### The fix

I don't know if the ECT sensor is a common issue on this Mustang. Before you buy a new sensor, make sure that the sensor signal is getting picked up by the ECU using a scan tool.

If you obtain no signal or a constant temperature readout via a scan tool while the engine is warming up, this would indicate a loose connection or bad sensor.

Hope this helps.

Comment: ^ This is best answer. Mark it as the correct one when the time comes.